# UIWebView Ajax Error in local html

Tags: ajax, uiwebview

UIWebVIew ajax error. I am loading local html from my app bundle in UIWebView. Html loaded into UIWebView again calls

```
  <

div class=“main”>
  </div>
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $.get("http://example.php", function( data ) {

     $(". main").html( data );//

   });
 });
    </script>
```

Now data is loading in div, but getting Ajax error.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to make it clear what it is that you are asking? If you are getting an error message can you copy it and paste that into the question? It can be formatted as a quote by putting a ">" in front of it.

Comment: Please check now